# Who originally invented this type of syntax: -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Tags: python, file, text, encoding, emacs

Python recognizes the following as instruction which defines file's encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I definitely saw this kind of instructions before (`-*- var: value -*-`), so I assume Python did not invent them and is not the only one that uses such instructions.

Where does this syntax come from? Is there full specification, e.g. can the value include spaces, special symbols, newlines, even `-*-` itself?

What other software recognizes such metadata syntax?

My program will be writing plain text files and I'd like to include some metadata in them using this format.

Comment: This is easier to remember and works in my editor, PyCharm.
`# coding: utf-8`

Comment: Using `# coding: utf8` works out of the box with Python 2.7, even outside of PyCharm. (I use SublimeText).

Comment: [File local variable in Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html), [cookie in SciTE](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html#Encodings), [Encoding declarations in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations) and [Modeline in Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6).

Comment: @Cbhihe This question is not about Python, not about what the instruction does or how it works. It is asking which pre-Python software invented it and if there is more to it than just file encoding.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This way of specifying the encoding of a Python file comes from [PEP 0263 - Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

It is also recognized by GNU Emacs (see [Python Language Reference, 2.1.4 Encoding declarations](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pylang/Encodingdeclarations.html)), though I don't know if it was the first program to use that syntax.

Comment: From what I can conclude from Emacs manual, value can be any LISP expression, particularly, a double-quoted string

Comment: Thanks for the pep link.  I was formerly under the impression that the directive was only used by the text editor.  Until now, I never knew that the python interpreter actually parsed the comment if it is present on the first two lines of the file.

Comment: The exact line comes from Python, but the general format is a emacs thing, as even Python documentation itself says at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code "The syntax is inspired by Emacs’s notation for specifying variables local to a file."

Answer (score 62):

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is a Python 2 thing.

In Python 3.0+ the default encoding of source files [is already UTF-8](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) so you can safely delete that line, because unless it says something other than [some variation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) of "`utf-8`", it has no effect. See [Should I use encoding declaration in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14083111/3064538)

---

[`pyupgrade`](https://pypi.org/project/pyupgrade/) is a tool you can run on your code to remove those comments and other useless leftovers from Python 2, like having all your classes inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 11):

This is so called file local variables, that are understood by Emacs and set correspondingly.  See corresponding [section in Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) - you can define them either in header or in footer of file

Comment: This specific type of file local variable is also understood by the Python interpreter itself, it's not just for text editors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680533/is-coding-utf-8-also-a-comment-in-python

Answer (score 4):

In PyCharm, I'd leave it out. It turns off the UTF-8 indicator at the bottom with a warning that the encoding is hard-coded. Don't think you need the PyCharm comment mentioned above.

Comment: actually, if I put a line like `test1 = 'äöü'` it will hint you to add such a headder to the file. (pycharm 2019.1)