# urllib.parse.quote won't take utf8

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to use urllib.parse.quote as intended but cant get it to work. I even tried the example given in the documentation

```
Example: quote('/El Niño/') yields '/El%20Ni%C3%B1o/'.
```

If I try this following happens.

```
quote('/El Niño/')
  File "<stdin>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 13: invalid continuation byte
```

Anyone got a hint what is wrong? I am using Python 3.2.3

PS: Link to the docs http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: What encoding was used for your source file? This error has nothing to do with `urllib`: Python is unable to parse your source file in the first place.

Comment: It happens when I just use the interpreter as well. So no source file

Comment: Worked for me from the interpreter. What's probably wrong is that your interpreter is not sure about what encoding your console or source file are using.

Comment: So how can I change that? Or if I called the function from a script how would it work? Btw for python 2 it works for me as well..

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\xf1` is a `latin-1` encoded `ñ`

```
>>> print(b'\xf1'.decode("latin-1"))
ñ
```

..not a utf-8 encoded character, like Python 3 [assumes by default](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/):

```
>>> print(b'\xf1'.decode("utf-8"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Meaning, there is an encoding issue either with the .py file you have written, or the terminal in which you are running the Python shell - it is supplying latin-1 encoded data to Python, not utf-8

Comment: I got it. My Putty was set to Latin-1 and my files were ANSI. Changed all to UTF-8, now it works :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following line at the begining of your source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
…
```

per default, python assumes that your source code is written in ASCII, and thus it can't read unicode strings from your source file. Read [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) on the topic.

Though, if you switch to python3, you don't need to place that `coding: utf-8` comment after the shebang line, because [utf-8 is the default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083111/python3-encoding-declaration).

*Edit*: Just noticed that you are actually trying to do python3, which should be utf-8-safe. Though looking at the error, it looks to me that you're actually executing python2 code whereas you think you are executing python3.

Is the shebang line correctly set?

Are you calling the script with the right interpreter?

here's the right shebang line:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
```

or

```
#/usr/bin/python3
```

and not just `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/env python`.

can you give your full failing script, and the way you're calling it in your question?