# invalid syntax error, tkinter, function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, syntax-error

When iIrun this program there is a syntax error and the '`def überprüfen()`' is marked red. What is wrong?

```
from tkinter import *
password = str(eval(entry.get())
```

In this part is the syntax error:

```
 def überprüfen(event):
     if password:
                if len(password) > 8:
                        res.configure(text = "Ihr Passwort ist zu kurz")
                else:
                        res.configure(text = "Ihr Passwort ist gut")
     else:
                res.configure(text = "Bitte geben sie ihr Passwort ein")


w = Tk()
Label(w, text="Ihr Passwort: ").pack()
entry = Entry(w)
entry.bind("<Return>", überprüfen())
entry.pack()
res = Label(w)
res.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

The program should test a password if it is good.
Thanks for helping :D

Comment: Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at first line of your source file. Or use the ascii characters to define identifiers.

Comment: The `from ... import` line shouldn't be indented, and neither should the `def` line.  Also, the `password =` line is missing the third `)`.

Comment: If you are really using Python 3, make sure that the file is saved as UTF-8. Nothing else needs to be done to allow unicode identifiers.

Comment: You say the `def` line *“is marked red”* – Where exactly are you looking at this? Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the first line of your code.

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Since OP is using Python 3, specifying the encoding explicitly like that [is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14083111/216074) and should probably even be avoided.