# Decoding and printing escaped characters

Tags: python, regex, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I have a regex substitution for the character `-`, replacing it with `»`. That all works just fine, however, when outputting the substituted result it is escaped. How do I properly print the characters upon output?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import os, sys
import re

searchText = "SKY ROCKETS IN FLIGHT - AFTERNOON DELIGHT"
result = re.sub("(\\-)", "»", searchText)
resultdecoded = result.decode('string_escape') 
print("output:", resultdecoded)
```

> ('output:', 'SKY ROCKETS IN FLIGHT \xc2\xbb AFTERNOON DELIGHT')

Comment: Take the parentheses off your `print`. This is obviously Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: @MarkRansom Wow, that was easy (and yes it's python 2). If you put that as an answer i'll gladly accept it. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, where `print` is a function, this would generate the correct output.

In Python 2, where `print` is a statement, you're not printing two different objects - you're printing a single tuple, created by putting the items in parentheses with a comma between them `(,)`. The string representation of a tuple tries to show how that string would look in the program.

The fix is to take off the parentheses.

Comment: One other question, what is the difference between `# coding: utf-8` and `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` — is using one or both more correct than the other?

Comment: @ctfd they'll both tell Python that your source file is utf-8. The one with the extra characters works with Emacs too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872007/where-does-this-come-from-coding-utf-8