# BS4 cannot read divs that appear in prettify?

Tags: python, html, wordpress, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse this website: [http://www.takeuchi-cycle.com/category/激安中古自転車情報/](http://www.takeuchi-cycle.com/category/%E6%BF%80%E5%AE%89%E4%B8%AD%E5%8F%A4%E8%87%AA%E8%BB%A2%E8%BB%8A%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1/)

```
import bs4
import requests


target_url = "http://www.takeuchi-cycle.com/category/激安中古自転車情報/"
response = requests.get(target_url)
response.raise_for_status()
```

I then soupify it:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
```

However, when I try to do `soup.find("div", {"id": "maincolumn"})`, I get the following:

```
<div id="maincolumn">
    <div class="post">
        <h2>Not Found</h2>
        <div class="entry">
            <p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

This bit appears neither on the website nor in soup.prettify(). Instead, all the listings appear. `soup.select("div")` and `soup.findAll("div", class_="post")` return similar things too. `html5lib` does not work, and I cannot access `lxml.parser` even though I have lxml installed.

What is causing this, and what can I do to make it work?

edit: Changing the URL to http://www.takeuchi-cycle.com/category/%E6%BF%80%E5%AE%89%E4%B8%AD%E5%8F%A4%E8%BB%8A%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1/ makes it work. But the content for both is identical except for the title. The first one says "page not found", I guess because it couldn't find the useragent, while the other says "For PC." The question remains, though.

Comment: Are you sure that `maincolumn` is not present because when I use `'maincolumn' in soup.prettify()` it returns `True`. And, I can also see it on the website.

Comment: That's why I asked this question. I see all the listings in `prettify`, and all the posts are populated.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955978/python-requests-url-with-unicode-parameters) had similar issues. Please have a look.