# Character count of Unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

How would I get the character count of the below in python?

```
s = 'הוא אוסף אתכם מחר בשלוש וחצי.'

Char count: 29
Char length: 52

len(s) = 52
? = 29
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`decode` your byte string (according to whatever encoding it's in, utf-8 maybe) -- the `len` of the resulting Unicode string is what you're after.

If fact best practice is to decode inputs as soon as possible, deal **only** with actual text (i.e, `unicode`, in Python 2; it's just the way ordinary strings are, in Python 3) in your code, and if need be `encode` just as you're outputting again.

Byte strings should be handled in your program only if it's specifically about byte strings (e.g, controlling or monitoring some hardware device, &c) -- far more programs are about text, and thus, except where indispensable at some I/O boundaries, they should be exclusively dealing with **text** strings (spelled `unicode` in Python 2:-).

But if you do want to keep `s` as a bytestring nevertheless,

```
len(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

(or whatever other encoding you're using to represent text as byte strings) should still do what you request.

Answer (score 3):

Use a unicode string

```
    s = 'הוא אוסף אתכם מחר בשלוש וחצי.'
    len(s) #52
    s = u'הוא אוסף אתכם מחר בשלוש וחצי.'
    len(s) #29
```

Comment: I get `Unsupported characters in input`.

Comment: Maybe a Python 2 thing?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi and Bjorn, so the two of you are using different encodings in your sources or interactive interpreter or IDE or whatever -- neither is on the Python 2 default encoding of `ascii`, clearly, so you might want to check:-)

Comment: I'm using IDLE, is there a way I can change the encoding.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: See [_Where does this come from: -*- coding: utf-8 -*-_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872007/where-does-this-come-from-coding-utf-8) and try adding it to the top of your script. I'm not sure if IDLE honors this or not...but it should.