# Why do I get a UnicodeDecodeError after reading my ping with Python?

Tags: python

to make my job easier, i am currently working on a network tool script to find out which switches are online/offline on my network using python. i have this short code:

```
import os

ping = os.popen("ping 9.9.9.9").read()
print(ping)

input("close")
```

at home this code runs fine, but when I run this code on my work VM I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\..\Documents\network_tool.py", line 3, in <module>
    ping = os.popen("ping 9.9.9.9").read()
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 18: character maps to <undifed_>
```

thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: with other cmd commands like "dir" it works, but commands starting with the letter "p", like "pause" or "ping", lead to this error

Comment: The real solution here is to set the encoding correctly on the stream. You're getting this error because you're trying to print to a CP1252 terminal, and Python is automatically detecting that. Set your stream encoding to utf-8 and things should work fine. Sometimes, Python is trying to be too smart!

Comment: You could also try using `subprocess.run` which provides a very nice low level API for this kinda of stuff: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Answer (score 0):

try to add

> `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

at the top of the file

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: The magic encoding comment only affects strings in your Python source code, not anything coming from outside.

Comment: are python versions different?

Comment: python 3.10.4 is installed on both machines

Comment: Please explain why you think this would help the OP. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` [declares the decoding of the source file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4872242/1707427), not the encoding `os.popen()` uses. And in python 3 the [default is utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652741/1707427) anyway, so there is no point in using `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found a workarount now. to do this you have to change line 177, in the file "..\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py".

from this:

```
'\ufffe'   #  0x81 -> UNDEFINED
```

to this

```
'p'   #  0x81 -> UNDEFINED
```

Comment: An easier workaround would be to get it to use `latin-1` instead of `cp1252`. But that doesn't explain where the 0x81 is coming from.